# Joda dateTime parser is adding milliseconds unnecessarily

Tags: java, jodatime

I have the time in milliseconds which I need to convert to `2009-01-31T06:34:45Z` using Joda library. I have written the below program but the date parser is adding milliseconds by default.

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
String str = fmt.print(dateTime);
System.out.println("Date as string - " + str);

dateTime = fmt.parseDateTime(str);
System.out.println("Date as Joda dataTime - " + dateTime);
```

Following is the output:

```
Date as string - 2007-03-24T23:03:44Z
Date as Joda dataTime - 2007-03-24T23:03:44.000+05:30
```

`.000+05:30` is getting added to the `dateTime` object. The `print` method print the dateTime in correct format, but the `parse` method adds milliseconds and timezone unnecessarily. Please let me know the mistake in the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `.000+05:30` is getting added to the dateTime object

No, it's included in the result of `dateTime.toString()`, that's all. A `DateTime` value doesn't have any concept of its own format - it's *just* a date/time/calendar/zone. If you want to convert a `DateTime` value to a specific format, you need to go through the formatter again - which you clearly know how to do, as you're already doing it in your code.

It's very important to distinguish between "the data in the object" and "the text representation you want". A `DateTime` is *always* stored with a precision of milliseconds, regardless of what it happened to be parsed from.